# how to get a particular cell from a dynamically added row based on its id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with the id `line-creation-table` which grows or shrinks dynamically. Each row in this table looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="brand" /></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="itemRefNo" id="itemRefNo"/></td>

    <td> <input type="number" name="quantity" value="1"/></td>

    <td> <input type="text" name="unitPrice" /></td>

    <td><input type="date" name="deliveryDate" /></td>

    <td><input type="button" value="Show Previous Actions" id="showPreviousActions"/></td>

</tr>
```

these rows are added dynamically. Now when the `showPreviousActions` button is clicked I want to retrieve the value from `itemRefNo` cell from the row where the button is clicked.

I tried this:

```
$("#line-creation-table").on('click', 'input[id="showPreviousActions"]', function(event) {
    var itemRefNo = $(this).parent().find('input[id="itemRefNo"]').val();
}
```

and this:

```
var itemRefNo = $(event.target).closest('input[id="itemRefNo"]').val();
```

but neither worked. When I console log the `itemRefNo` variable I get `undefined`. How can I solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: .....$(this).parent().siblings(':has(input[id="itemRefNo"])').find('input')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
$(this).parent()
```

takes the current item (this = the button) and gets its parent, which is the `td` of the button, so attempting to then find an input in an adjacent cell fails.

A quick fix would be to get the `td`s parent, the `tr`, giving:

```
$("#line-creation-table").on('click', 'input[id="showPreviousActions"]', function(event) {
    var itemRefNo = $(this).parent().parent()
                        .find('input[id="itemRefNo"]').val();
}
```

better would be to use `closest()` to find the button's row:

```
$("#line-creation-table").on('click', 'input[id="showPreviousActions"]', function(event) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var itemRefNo = row.find('input[id="itemRefNo"]').val();
}
```

Where [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/%20closest) is the same as calling `.parent()` recursively until it finds a matching node (ie, closest parent).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response @freedomn-m. I just tried both of your suggestions but I still get undefined. It works on the statically created row though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('#showPreviousActions').click(function () {
            var aa = $(this).closest('tr').find('#itemRefNo').val();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this won't get invoked as the rows are added dynamically @Uttam Gupta. Therefore I need to add the event listener to the table.

Comment: I am seeing each button in a row having same id ie showPreviousAction, i suggest you can use class instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a very stupid mistake on my side. When creating a row for this table dynamically, I forgot to change the code there so that in the newly created rows there would be an input with the id `itemRefNo`. The old code:

```
$('#line-creation-table').append("<tr>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='brand' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemRefNo' /></td>" +
                "<td> <input type='number' name='quantity' value='1'/></td>" +
                "<td> <input type='text' name='unitPrice' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='date' name='deliveryDate' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' value='Show Previous Actions' id='showPreviousActions'/></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' value='Delete' id='deleteRowButton' /></td>" +
                "</tr>")
```

new code:

```
$('#line-creation-table').append("<tr>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='brand' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='text' name='itemRefNo' id='itemRefNo'/></td>" +
                "<td> <input type='number' name='quantity' value='1'/></td>" +
                "<td> <input type='text' name='unitPrice' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='date' name='deliveryDate' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' value='Show Previous Actions' id='showPreviousActions'/></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button' value='Delete' id='deleteRowButton' /></td>" +
                "</tr>")
```

So both of @freedomn-m 's suggestions work.